# how to put the two fingers right click(secondary click) on macbook with Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, contextual-menu

I have a late 2009 macbook which has the trackpad with division, unlike the ones that are in market right now. I upgraded to Mountain Lion(10.8.x) but I forgot how to enable the Secondary two fingers right-click. Can someone help to get it working.

Thanks,

uDaY

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences > Trackpad > Secondary Click > "Click or tap with two fingers"

[image]

Comment: Sorry  I have seen this, but I dont find this kind of GUI only... my trackpad has division which dates back to 2009 macbook(white) models..